# Apache mod rewrite page.ext?qstring to go.php?parms="page.ext?qstring"

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have spent hours trying to figure out how to do a rewrite that will take the page requested along with any query string provided and feed them into a php script for processing. This is in connection with writing a restful API where the `go.php` script will decide what to do based on the page requested and any arguments passed to it via a query string. One difficulty is encoding the ? and = in the query string, but these could be replaced with anything.

Example

```
customer.json?action=add,id=123,name=smith
```

maps to

```
go.php?parms=customer.json?action=add,id=123,name=smith
```

where "`customer.json?action=add,id=123,name=smith`" is treated as a string, that is the = , ? do not throw things out. If necessary alternative chars could be substituted for these.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer to my own question. The `.htaccess` file in the directory containing the `go.php` script needs to be

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ go.php?page=$1;%1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

This will map as follows. Suppose the `go.php` script is in the `example.com/api` directory.

1. The 1st and 2nd `RewriteCond` statements return any files or
   directories that actually exist in the api directory.
2. The 3rd and 4th `RewriteCond` statements capture any query string in the URL
   into a variable called `%1`. The 3rd statement handles the no query
   string case.
3. The last `RewriteRule` statement captures the resource name under the api directory 
   in the URL into a variable called `$1`. It then calls the `go.php` script       and passes in the new query string consisting of 
   the resource name followed by a `;` followed by the original query string.

Some examples

1. If 'junk.html`exists in`/api` it will be returned.
2. If 'sub/junk.html`exists in`/api` it will be returned.
3. If `customer.json` does not exist in `/api` then 
   `customer.json?id=123,name=smith` will invoke the `go.php` and pass it a single query string variable called `page` with value `customer.json;id=123,name=smith`.

The idea behind all of this is to use it in RESTful APIs. In the 3rd example above `customer` is the resource, `json` is the representation, and the rest are parameters. The `go.php` script can use this data to execute an HTTP verb on a resource and return the requested representation.

Why am I doing this. Often in database applications resources have lots of parameters so creating and updating resources would look a little cumbersome if we used nested `/` to pass in all these parameters, which is what pure RESTful APIs require, as I understand it.

To test the above `Rewrite` code here is a simple `go.php` script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Go Baby</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$page = "NIX";
if(isset($_GET["page"])) 
  $page = $_GET["page"];
echo "Passed in page $page";
?>
```